# spring mvc validator @valid doesn't work for collections

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, collections, invoke

I've been using Spring MVC and hibernate annotations to validate incoming request objects, and that was all fine and dandy until I need to validate an incoming collection.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/guests", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Set<GuestResource>> postGuestsToAttendance(
        @Valid @RequestBody Set<RequestToAddGuest> guestRequests) throws FieldValidationException,
        RequestBodyResourceBadRequestException
```

As I figured, it tried to perform validation on the Set itself and not on the individual members inside it.

After a bit of research, I couldn't find any 'easy' solutions, but instead found a bit on custom validators and invoking them. Since I don't really require a custom validator, just a way to invoke validation for each item in the set, I tried to get that all working, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my invocation code:

```
for (RequestToAddGuest guestRequest : guestRequests) {
        // Perform validation
        BindingResult bindingResults = new DirectFieldBindingResult(guestRequest, RequestToAddGuest.class.getName());
        validator.validate(guestRequests, bindingResults);
        checkForErrors(bindingResults);
    }
```

Here is the checkForErrors code. It worked great when I used @Valid on a solitary object only.

```
protected void checkForErrors(BindingResult results) throws FieldValidationException {
    if (results.hasErrors()) {
        FieldValidationException exception = new FieldValidationException();
        exception.setFieldErrors(results.getFieldErrors());
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

And for reference, here is the RequestToAddGuest class with the validation annotations:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.SafeHtml;

public class RequestToAddGuest {

    @NotEmpty
    @SafeHtml
    public String firstName;

    @SafeHtml
    @NotEmpty
    public String lastName; 

    @SafeHtml
    public String emailAddress;

    @SafeHtml
    public String streetLine1;

    @SafeHtml
    public String streetLine2;

    @SafeHtml
    public String streetLine3;

    @SafeHtml
    public String city;

    @SafeHtml
    public String stateCode;

    @SafeHtml
    public String zip;

    @SafeHtml
    public String countryCode;

    @SafeHtml
    public String phoneArea;

    @SafeHtml
    public String phoneNumber;

    @SafeHtml
    public String phoneExtension;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the issue... I had gotten so caught up in the validation code, I had overlooked keeping track of my variable names... I had never changed the validation invocation to be called on the individual guestRequest, rather than on the whole list named guestRequest**s**